# ESP32 attempt reconnect to when network drops without halting loop (Arduino)

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32

I have an ESP 32 collect data from a moisture sensor, which it then serves on our network. Our WiFi turns off between 1am and 6 am (because no one is using it). The ESP does not automatically try to reconnect, so it gathered data all night which I straight up can not access now.

For obvious reasons I do not want it to halt data collection when it looses connection to our network, so I can not have a loop try to reconnect. I tried this code:

```
void loop() {
  sensor_value = analogRead(sensor_pin);
  Serial.println(sensor_value);
  push_value(float(sensor_value)/2047.0);
  
  //============
  //RELEVANT BIT
  //============

  if( WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED ){
    //Try to recconect if connection is lost....
    WiFi.disconnect();
    WiFi.begin(ssid, pwd);
  }
  
  delay(second_delay*1000);
}
```

I've seen everyone run `Wifi.disconnect()` before attempting reconnecting. Is that necessary. Also does `WiFi.begin()` pause execution? I can't test my code right now unfortunately.

I am using the Arduino IDE and Wifi.h

And before you ask: Yes, 2047 is correct. I am running the sensor on the wrong voltage which results in about this max value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you've tagged esp8266 wifi, I'm assuming you're using that library. If so, then wifi.begin will not block execution. The library sets autoreconnect by default, so it'll automatically reconnect to the last access point when available. Any client functions will simply return an error code while disconnected. I do not know of any reason that wifi.disconnect should be called before begin.

Comment: That tag might be badly chosen. I am using the Arduino IDE with the ESP32 plugin and the I am import WiFi.h. Those might be the same library but I am not sure. I am certain that that library does not set autorecconect as a default because when I woke up today I could not access the data.